# ssh woes with openSSH in windows

Tags: windows, openssh

So i am having a rather severe issue with setting up OpenSSH for password-less entry on my university supplied computer.

There are 2 main issues:

**1.** The default config and known_hosts file created by openSSH upon first use default to the university h: directory. This is a local directory so i would need to be connected to the local network or using a VPN which isn't always the case. So the first question is, how can i change where the openSSH looks for known_hosts and config.

[image]

**2.** The second issue is that when i try to set up passwordless entry. It is that the openssh client tells me that my private key is not protected which is fair enough, but what is the best way to change the permissions because I have tried through windows properties and it is hopeless.

Comment: I fixed this  by using CopSSH in case anyone was interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was only fixable by changing to a different SSH program, copSSH.